# How do I make decisions based on presence of resource in Azure inside ARM?

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I need my ARM template to use conditional statement based on presence of Azure Files share. How do I find out if fileshare exists inside ARM to deploy certain other types of resources based on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no simple way to do this... ARM is declarative and should be idempotent.  But you could work around the scenario by using a deploymentScript to check existence.